# Script to combine movie audio tracks in order to learn a language

Tags: command-line, language-support, extract, mkv

I would like to build a special script to learn English from a movie (dvd, mkv ...). I would like to extract the audio part in my native language then in English and the subtitles with the timeline. The subtitles will allow me to know when the actors speak.

From there, the native and English audio tracks are cut out. Then re-assembled to have for each sentence:

**Sentence 1:** The track in native && pause 2 seconds && the track in English && Pause 4 seconds.

**Sentence 2:** The track in native && pause 2 seconds && the track in English && Pause 4 seconds

etc.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: You may wan't to check out [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). It wont be a very easy task.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to learn a new language there is an easier method: play the English audio and display the subtitles in your native language.

That's how I learned (and am still learning):

- Français
- English
- Deutsch
- Afrikaans
- по-русски
- ...

Comment: You disappoint me @fabby No Dutch?

Comment: I'm perfectly bilingual already! @Rinzwind  What else is there to learn???  **:D**

Comment: P.S.  Johann: Et vous seriez étonné au nombre de mots commun en Anglais et en Français: Avalanche,     Information,
    Attention,
    Communication,
    Transformation,
    Compétition,
    Justification,
    Action,
    Connexion,
    Télévision, ...

Comment: basically everything ending in *-ion*, who would have thought of that? ;P

Comment: @Fabby... `connexion` in French but `connection` in English :)

Comment: @Fabby Thank William the Conqueror, who crossed the Channel and crowned himself King of England. He introduced a *ton* of Latin and French vocabulary to English; there are actually more words of Latin origin in English than there are words of older Germanic or British origin.

Comment: @Rinzwind afrikaans is so close you could say you know some dutch. "As an estimated 90 to 95% of Afrikaans vocabulary is ultimately of Dutch origin" - from wikipedia.

Comment: Yeah wel there are not a lot of Dutch people that would understand what they mean with a hysbak. It might stem from it but no... impossible to understand to a dutch that did not study it.

Comment: @xenoid.  I couldn't remember enough words to get my point across.  And avalanche doesn't end in -ion.  **:-)**

Answer (score 6):

SMPlayer can display two subtitles at the same time. The first subtitle is shown on the bottom of the image, the second one on the top.

You need mvp + smplayer for this. That would lower the need to cut it up.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried yet but I've been meaning to check out [Subs2Srs](http://learnanylanguage.wikia.com/wiki/Subs2srs). Maybe it can help you. On the site it says:

> subs2srs is a small utility that allows you to create Anki import files based on your favorite foreign language movies and TV shows to aid in the language learning process.
>
> This utility will parse through a subtitle file, extract the dialog and timing information, and then use that information to generate audio clips, snapshots, and video clips for each line of dialog.

You might not want Anki files but it might get you close enough. Sorry, I think it needs Windows but maybe you have that available.

Comment: Subs2Srs is Windows Software which requires a lot of fighting to get it working under Wine, so not something for a rep 16 user...  **-1, sorry**